# XAMPP Apache not starting because of Apache2.4

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp, apache2.4

So I'm starting to use MySQL and phpMyAdmin and I firstly installed Apache2.4. After installing Apache2.4 there were numerous errors so I decided to install XAMPP instead. Now me not thinking through the consequences deleted the Apache2.4 Folder completely along with all its contents.

So now when I start XAMPP, MySQL runs fine but Apache is stuck on "Attempting to start Apache service..." Now when I look at the services tab Apache2.4 is still on my list, I have disabled it but it's made no difference. I have checked through my computer for any remaining Apache2.4 files but I can't find any.

If anyone can help me with this, it would be extremely helpful!

UPDATE: I have restored Apache24 from my recycling bin, should I attempt a uninstall using cmd?

Comment: Give us the error log, without it we wont be able to help much

Answer (score 0):

It appears that an instance of apache 2.4 is running on the system. It is probably locking port 80 which the reason why XAMPP apache is unable to start.

Shutdown apache 2.4 from it's control panel, shutdown the service, and ensure there is no "httpd" process running using task manager.  If there is kill it.

Once the above are done you should be able to start xampp.

Answer (score 0):

Follow those steps:

```
1- Uninstall Apache 2.4
2- Clean Windows Registry with a tool like CCleaner
3- Restart Windows
4- Install XAMPP
```

Comment: Could you expand on how to uninstall it, I'm having trouble finding it in Control Panel and access is denied on CMD?